# Prestashop 1.6 - Show Customer Group in Account page (Front End)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created 5 customer groups in back-end for my customers. I assigned a customer group for each of them based on orders.

I would like to show customer groups in front-end for every customer in his account details page.

Best would be to create a new tab in account details page and when he click there he can see in what group he is and some text about group system.

I tried to search but there is no module or anything on the market.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be achieved by implementing a custom module.

If you are interested in custom module development, we can work to help you in adding this feature to your store.

We are a leading developer of PrestaShop and have also earned SuperHero badge. You can check our modules and rating on the following link:

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/2_community-developer?contributor=38002

Comment: no budget for this, looking for help not for offer. but thanks!